# run a Js script bot every time that a page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, bots

i'm new in firefox add-on dev

I'm triyng to run a contentscriptScript in a active tab which click on a random link into the tab, **it's works**

But i'm trying to repeat this operation in the new webpage in an endlessly way, like a kind of WebBot.
i dont know if i have to implement this setting in the contentScript or in the Main.js , SetInterval and SetTimeOut seems to doesnt work.

Here the ContentScript.

```
var webs = []; // all links
var l = document.links; //get all links
var unwebs; //new WebPage

function browse(){

    // find links
    for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
      webs.push(l[i].href);
    }

    //pick a random link
    unwebs = webs[Math.floor(Math.random()*webs.length)];

}

function clickLink(){

    //redirection
    window.location.href = unwebs ;

}


$(document).ready(function(){

    browse();
    clickLink();
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, this works alright, but it just isn't repeating forever like you want it to?

Comment: yep this code works,but I don't find solutions to repeat the functions in the new page.

Comment: Just an FYI, once you get this working, you'll want `setInterval` over `setTimeout`.

Comment: ok, i tried smthg like this 'function start() { // your code here setTimeout(start, 3000); } // boot up the first call start(); ' or stackoverflow.com/questions/8421998/setinterval-with-loop-time without result :-(

Comment: AFAIK content script unloads when page unloads, when your new page loaded then your old page along with content script unloaded and hence it will not execute for new page.

Comment: `pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.org",
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-2.1.0.min.js"), self.data.url("onescript.js")]
});
` If use this in the Page Script, it's look like what i want, but it is possible to use this only in one tab, to limit this at one tab. Not the others?

Comment: Before i used tab.attach to add contentscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [tabs docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#ready)

### main.js

```
var tab = require('sdk/tabs').activeTab;
tab.on('ready', function() {
  //attach content script with tab.attach
});
```